# how to highlight the entire row of data in the datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a data grid view in C# form which displays  the contents of a sql database table.
when the datagridview loads i want the row which contains the current date to be highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will have to find the row containing today's date:

```
int dateColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns["e_date"].Index;// < replace with your actual date column name
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[dateColumnIndex].Value is DateTime)
    {
        DateTime colDate = (DateTime)row.Cells[dateColumnIndex].Value;
        if (colDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
        {
            row.Selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }                
}
```

Just make sure that your `DataGridView`'s [selection mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set to `FullRowSelect`:

`dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;`

Comment: int dateColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf("Date-Column-Name"); i modified the above line to .....int dateColumnIndex = dataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf("e_date").... im getting the error.. invalid arguments

Comment: @Brian I did not understand your comment.

Comment: i hav edited the comment please have a look

Comment: @Brian I have modified my answer

Comment: Error 3 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('System.DateTime' is a non-nullable value type)......im getting the above error on line :- DateTime colDate = row.Cells[dateColumnIndex].Value as DateTime;

Comment: @Brian yup, that's what you get for writing an answer without a compiler... Fixed...

Comment: aah i didnt get u.. so what changes should i make?

Comment: ן changed my code: `row.Cells[dateColumnIndex].Value is DateTime`

Comment: thanks alot..... just one more question.. instead of highlighting it can i change the background color of that row.

Comment: @Brian you can accomplish that by setting the [DataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property. For example:: `row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;`

Answer (score -1):

The idea is, loop thru your result list to get those rows that you wish to highligh, and set the selectedRow as below:

```
myDataGrid.Rows[n].IsSelected = true;
```